# How to replace value for all keyframes?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I recorded an animation with my object `z` set to 1.00 but realised afterwards it needs to be at 3.00 throughout.

How can I set the object's `z` to 3.00 for all selected keyframes in the dopesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to change its Z position throughout the animation, you can do it with the *Graph Editor*:

- Select your object, open the *Graph Editor*.
- Unfold the *LocRotScale* of the object and lock everything except the *Z* Location.
- Select the curve and move it up 2 units with <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> (Y is the up axis of the *Graph Editor*).
- Now your object is 2 units up on the *Z* axis.

[image]

Now, about your second question: "If some of my z positions are not 1, but a different value, is there a way to set them all at once, rather than shift them all by the same value?"

Trick to align several vertices on the same axis:

- Select the vertice that is your Y reference, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to move your green cursor up to this vertice
- Select the vertices you want to align on the same Y position.
- <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor Value*.

Better trick suggested by Mr Zak:

- Select the vertice #1 which is the Y position reference.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to make the cursor move to the vertice position.
- Select the 2D Cursor as the *Pivot Point*.
- Select all the vertices you want to snap to the Y position.
- Scale down to zero with <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. And if some of my z positions are not 1, but a different value, is there a way to set them all at once, rather than shift them all by the same value?

Comment: you could select the vertice in the Graph Editor and in the N panel > Key Value > Enter the value. I don't see any Snap option in the Graph Editor, which would have been really convenient to a vertice to the other ones, I guess we should ask a new question on this particular point

Comment: So, I've created a question to know if there's a Snap option in the Graph Editor. Anyway there's a way to do it. Select the vertice that is your reference, ctrl G to move your green cursor up to this vertice, select your other vertices and shift S > Cursor Value.

Comment: If you select on the graph editor all the keyframes and press S Y 0 (scale on the Y axis to zero), you will assign a single value to all, that can then be adjusted pressing G Y and Enter.